# Does Assets fields work in Calendar (solspace)

Tags: assets, solspace-calendar

I have an assets field being used inside a {exp:calendar:events entry and the field is not parsing.

```
<img src="{calendar:event_photo:url:thumb}" title="listing image">
```

is notparsed at all

```
<img src="{calendar:event_photo}" title="listing image">
```

is parsed as

```
<img src="imagefilename.jpg" title="listing image">
```

but is missing the full path.

Is there somethign within Calendar that is not allowing me to use :url:thumb??

Answer (score 1):

While the *Calendar:Events* template tag may work similarly to the EE *Channel:Entries* tag, it is much more limited. This is because Calendar looks at event recurrence rules and populates the additional occurrences that way (rather than the recurrences actually existing in database). This inflates the counts and can take a huge hit on performance. In Calendar 1.x we had a large number of customers complain about performance issues, so in Calendar 2.x we sacrificed some extra *Channel:Entries* functionality in favor of huge performance gains. We did this by rewriting our own version of the *Channel:Entries* functionality and just included what we believed to be the more commonly used features. Unfortunately some features such as search parameter and third party field types are limited or not built in at this time.

In the particular case of images, there is limited support for EE file fields, and you can read more about that here:
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/docs/events/#your_custom_field

In some cases it works to embed a template with *Channel:Entries* tag to parse extra variables or conditionals, but in the case of filling the gaps for excluded parameters, I don't believe there is an easy way around it unfortunately.